# How do I validate uniqueness of join table with extra column in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a has many through relationship in a model that is self referencing.  In the join table I also have an extra column that defines the source of the relationship.  When adding a new object to that relationship I'd like to avoid duplicates in the join table based on the user_id, friend_id, and source_id

User Model

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :friendships
      has_many :friends, :class_name => "User", :through => :friendships
 end
```

Join Model

```
 class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
     attr_accessible :friend_id, :user_id, :source_id, :alert, :hide

     # Relationships
     belongs_to :user
     belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User"
     has_one :source
 end
```

I understand that I can do this

```
 unless user.friends.include?(newFriend)
      user.friendships.build(:friend_id => friendUser.id, :source_id => source.id)
 end
```

But that seems like it will check to see if the new user exists in the current user's friends.  I need to check on the join model level and make sure that the connection doesn't exist with the given source id.

I know there are several ways to accomplish this, but I'm pretty new to ruby on rails and am looking for the "rails way" to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can validate based on multiple columns in your intermediate table like this:

```
  validates_uniqueness_of :user_id, :scope => [:friend_id, :source_id]
```

Comment: Excellent.  Will that give me an error on save? Or will that just not save the duplicate record?

Comment: Will that just die silently? Or do I have to do a begin/rescue every time I save one?

Comment: well you should probably promt the user that (s)he is trying to do a invalid action, shouldn't you? You should do the `if save` redirect to somewhere, everything's okay `else` render the page or somehow with a flash notice say to the user that its an invalid action `end`. If you don't want nothing to happen when the user clicks to make the double record, you should just do a `save` action in the controller. If its unique, it will save it, if its not then nothing happens

Comment: Sounds good.  I'm mostly looking at updates.  This is all happening in a restful service.  At the end of the day whether that save succeeds or fails because of a duplication is irrelevant to the user as long as the relationship exists at the end of the process.  So as long as I do something like this in my controller I should be ok.  `friendship = user.friendships.build(:friend_id => friendUser.id, :source_id => source.id); friendship.save;`

Comment: yes, and redirect it to somewhere, right? :) Try it out, that is the best teacher :)